# Why "LAST_INSERT_ID()" doesn't return anything here in a MySQL reader?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-core

I am trying to understand why the second `LAST_INSERT_ID()` command doesn't return anything in the reader after executing `addInvoiceCommand`. The reader keeps returning 0 rows. The first reader after `addClientCommand` works fine.

```
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();


                var addClientCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                addClientCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO client(clientName)
                VALUES(@ClientName);"; 

                
                addClientCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", input.Client.ClientName);
                addClientCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                var selectLastIdCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                string lastInsertedId = "";
                selectLastIdCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";

                using var reader = await selectLastIdCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   lastInsertedId = reader[0].ToString();
                }

                reader.Close();


                
                var addInvoiceCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                addInvoiceCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO invoice(client_id,
                description, paymentTerms, invoiceDate, paymentDueDate,BillFromAddress,
                BillFromCity, BillFromCountry, BillFromPostal)
                VALUES(@client_id, @Description, @PaymentTerms, @InvoiceDate, @PaymentDueDate,
                @BillFromAddress, @BillFromCity,  @BillFromCountry, @BillFromPostal);";

                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", Int32.Parse(lastInsertedId));
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", input.Description);
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentTerms", input.PaymentTerms);
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceDate", input.InvoiceDate);
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentDueDate", input.PaymentDue);
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillFromAddress", input.BillFromAddress);
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillFromCity", input.BillFromCity);
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillFromCountry", input.BillFromCountry);
                addInvoiceCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillFromPostal", input.BillFromPostal);
                addInvoiceCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
               

                var lastInvoiceIdCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                string lastInvoiceId = "";
                lastInvoiceIdCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";

                using var readerLastInvoiceId = await lastInvoiceIdCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (readerLastInvoiceId.Read())
                {
                    lastInvoiceId = reader[0].ToString();
                }

                readerLastInvoiceId.Close();
```

Comment: I suppose that is due to the fact that a datareader cannot serve two commands on the same connection. Can you verify if the the second record has been inserted even if the reader returns 0?

Comment: What happens if you do it as a single batch? `INSERT ... ; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` and then use `ExecuteScalarAsync()`? Also if you decide to use a reader and you want async, you should use `.ReadAsync()`

Comment: I think the problem was I was using the same reader object twice within the same connection.  In the the second while loop I wrote `reader[0]` invoking the reader used before instead of `readerLastInvoiceId[0]`.

Comment: If you don't await `addClientCommand` it will execute the next command before the first has completed.